# requirement on proposition

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I want to draw a conclusion from an equivalent description of a relation.

Let $R$ be a relation on a set $M$ with $R \subseteq M \times M$.

First I have 2 examples of what I mean:

1. $x \sim_R y \Longleftrightarrow 1 = 1$, which obviously means $R = M \times M$
2. Let $M = \mathbb{N}$ and $F(x) = 1$ for all even $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$ else.

   $x \sim_R y \Longleftrightarrow F(x) = F(y)$

   In this case it's easy to see, that $\sim_R$ is an equivalence relation, hence we were able to show the equivalence of $\sim_R$ to an equality.

But actually I want to be more abstract. I want to examine cases of the following:

$R$ is still a relation on a set $M$ with $R \subseteq M \times M$.
It holds that:

$x \sim_R y \Longleftrightarrow F(x) = F(y)$ where $F(x), F(y)$ are 'missing word'.

What can $F(x), F(y)$ be? Sure, they are propositions, but they can't be *any* proposition, since you have to be able to compare $F(x)$ and $F(y)$ in terms of equality. How do I describe this circumstance mathematically correct?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are looking for, but you can always define $F(x) = [x]$ the equivalence class of $x$, that is, $F: M \to M/\sim$.

Comment: It's really hard for me to explain what I am looking for. I want a description of what F(x) and F(y) can be in the most abstract case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're wondering about two different though related things, and are coming close to confusing them:

1. How general a definition can one give for a function $F$?, and
2. Given any function, can one define an equivalence relation on the domain of $F$ by $$x \sim_F y \iff F(x) = F(y)\ ?$$

The answer to 2. is, absolutely yes. Regarding 1., however, I'm not sure what you mean, and your example about '$F(x)$ and $F(y)$ are "missing word"' is a bit confusing. This $F$ is supposed to have string values, in the alphabet $\{a,b,c,...,z\}$? What's its domain (what are $x,y$)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I was able to solve my problem. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1520337/283569

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve my problem. It was wrong to try anything with 'propositions'. I needed functions. I was able to prepare two lemmata.

Lemma 1:
Be $Z$ a set and be $\sim_R$ an equivalence relation on a set $M$. Be $f$ a function with $f\colon\, M\to Z$ and $g$ a function with $g\colon\, M\to M$, with:
\begin{align}
&\forall x,y \in M: f(x) = f(y) \implies g(x) = g(y)\\
&\forall x \in M: x \sim_R g(x)
\end{align}
Now it follows: $$\forall x,y \in M: f(x) = f(y) \implies x \sim_R y$$

Lemma 2:
Be $Z$ a set and be $\sim_R$ a relation on a set $M$. Be also $f$ a (surjective) function with $f\colon\, M\to Z$. Also be $X \subseteq M$, with $f|_X$ bijective, with: \begin{align}\forall x,y \in M: x \sim_R y \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)\end{align}
(This is enough to prove that $\sim_R$ is an equivalence relation.)
Now it follows: $$M/{\sim_R} = \{[a]_{\sim_R} \mid a \in X\} $$
It also holds: $$\forall x,y \in X: x \sim_R y \implies x = y$$

Comment: Sorry, that's more a linguistic problem right now. I meant that $\forall x,y \in M: x \sim_R y \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)$ is a part of the assumption. In practice I have to find this function $f$ first. But after finding it, I could use my lemma. How would I express that correctly? And the R in $\sim_R$ should simply stand for 'relation'

Comment: I don't understand your Lemma 2. Why does it have to hold that $\forall x,y\in M\colon x\sim_R y \iff f(x) = f(y)$? You've already said "let $\sim_R$ be a relation on $M$", $\sim_R$ is given, so this can't be the definition of it; and then the result you state simply isn't so in general. // $\sim_R$ is not a good name for an arbitrary, not-necessarily-equivalence-, relation. It also strongly suggests a dependence on some $R$, but there's no $R$ anywhere in sight.

Comment: Changed a few words in Lemma 2. Is this better now?

Comment: (Sorry, I redid my previous comment & now our two previous comments are out of order.)  $R$ is a much better name for an arbitrary relation. $R$, for *relation*. So, that *is* the definition of the relation. Then yes it's an equiv relation, as usual. $f$ doesn't have to be surjective. You mean $f\!\restriction\!X$ is injective (same as, bijection from $X$ to its range :) Your final result is certainly true. But the 2nd to last identity is not true, in general: there can be equivalence classes of things in $M\setminus X$, containing nothing in $X$. $\supseteq$ is true, but not $\subseteq$.

Comment: Not really better, no -- same problems. // And one doesn't say "Be Z a set, be $X\subseteq M$", etc. One says "Let Z be a set", "let $X\subseteq M$", "also let $f$ be a (surjective) function...".

Comment: Ah: I think the condition on $f$ you have in mind is: $f[X] = f[M]$ and $f$ is 1-1 on $X$. That is, $f\!\restriction\! X$ is a bijection between $X$ and range$(f)$. Then both of your identities work :) because it guarantees that everything in $M$ is $\sim_R$-related to something in $X$.

Comment: I am going to rewrite everything later this day. I will also add my proof for the lemmata, I hope that everything will be clearer then. Sorry again - the mathematical english is completely new for me, it's not easy for me to express things like I could in german.

Comment: Ohh, no problem re the English. Just a tip about usage.

Comment: Just one last question. Do you actually mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics) by your $f \mid X$?

Comment: Yes exactly that. I wasn't aware I was using old-fashioned notation :) Thanks. Now that we've cleared that up, do you see what I mean about the requirement for $f$ and $X$?

Comment: Hello Brian! If you are interested in it, here is the new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1520577/283569